# Getting spinner to show what they picked

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

My `spinner` works but I want to know what user has selected before clicking on the `confirm button` that I have set up. I was guessing something like setting the `spinners` to a `variable` so I can use them anywhere because as of right now the can only be used in the main body. any help would be much appreciated

```
public class Calculate extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{    
   int number = 0;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.calculate);

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hemsSpinner);
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.materialSpinner);

        Button butn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        butn1.setOnClickListener(this);


    // Selection of the spinner
    // Application of the Array to the Spinner

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Hems.Hem);
    spinnerArrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Material.Material);
    spinnerArrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);


    EditText qty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.qtyEditText);
    double quantity = qty.getId();

    EditText H = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightEditText);
    double hight = H.getId();

    EditText W = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.widthEditText);
    double width = W.getId();


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {


        if(Calculate.spinner1.equals(Hems.Hem[0]))
        {
            number = 0;
        }
        else if (spinner1.equals(Hems.Hem[1]))
            {
            number = 1;
            }
        else if (spinner1.equals(Hems.Hem[2]))
        {
            number = 2;
        }
        else if (spinner1.equals(Hems.Hem[3]))
        {
            number = 3;
        }


        if (v.getId() == R.id.calculateButton)
        {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(Hems.Hem[number]);

        TextView dude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dude.setText((int) Hems.hemPrice[number]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

declare your spinner as field

```
  Spinner spinner1,spinner2;
```

And then in your `onCreate` get their reference like this

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hemsSpinner);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.materialSpinner);
```

And the use `yourspinner.getSelectedItem()` method to get your spinner data when confirm button is pressed

Comment: you know now that i think about it,that code does make sense so thanks